# xlst code to change the labels in an affiliation text string to superscript

Tags: xml, xslt

XML:

```
<contrib-group>
<contrib/>
<contrib/>
<contrib/>
    <aff id="AFF1"><label>1</label>InstitutionZ, Paris, France, <label>2</label>Departmenty, Wolfenbuettel, Germany, <label>3</label>Departmentx, Croissy-Sur-Seine, France</aff>
```

I want to transforms the  to look like this,

```
<p><sup>1</sup>InstitutionZ, Paris, France,
<sup>2</sup>Departmenty, Wolfenbuettel, Germany, 
<sup>3</sup>Departmentx, Croissy-Sur-Seine, France</p>
```

I have tried this,

```
       <p><sup><xsl:value-of select="./label">
       </xsl:value-of></sup><xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
        </p>
```

But that only give me content between label 1 and label 2.

<sup>1</sup>InstitutionZ, Paris, France,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider a template based approach here. Simply write a template for each element in your XML that you want to change to HTML.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="aff">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="label">
        <sub>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </sub>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML

```
<aff id="AFF1">
   <label>1</label>InstitutionZ, Paris, France, 
   <label>2</label>Departmenty, Wolfenbuettel, Germany, 
   <label>3</label>Departmentx, Croissy-Sur-Seine, France
</aff>
```

The following is output

```
<p>
   <sub>1</sub>InstitutionZ, Paris, France, 
   <sub>2</sub>Departmenty, Wolfenbuettel, Germany, 
   <sub>3</sub>Departmentx, Croissy-Sur-Seine, France
</p>
```